# Library of Congress Classification, Subject Headings?

Tags: discussion

Is opendata a good place to ask about LOC classification and Subject Headings (LCSH)? It is open data (http://id.loc.gov/download/), but I fear there are very few interested in such very narrow topics.

Probably off-topic, is there any forum that deals with classification systems (in particular LOC)? Sorry for asking here, but I'm at my wits' ends and LOC itself doesn't seem to point to any discussion groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an appropriate place.

If others don't think it is, there are a number of groups out there with '4lib' in their names, which are library-related discussions.  Some places you might try, and if they're not right, people will be able to point you in the right direction:

- [code4lib](http://code4lib.org/): programmers in libraries (mailing list & conference; some local chapters)
- [ngc4lib](http://listserv.nd.edu/archives/ngc4lib.html) : next generation catalogs for libraries (mailing list; used to be a lot of FRBR/FRAD/RDA discussion, but still has a lot of catalogers on it)

Comment: Thanks. You may want to fix your 2 links :)

Comment: @dan3 : @#!%% copy & paste.